# Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync takes multiple seconds

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In my Windows 8 <s>Metro</s> new UI application, a call to `LaunchUriAsync` takes multiple seconds to execute. It simply opens the default browser with a given URL, but that shouldn't take that long. What's wrong?

Offending code:

```
Await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(New System.Uri("http://some.url.com/my-page"))
```

The delay is only there while I am online. When I'm offline, Internet Explorer immediately opens (and fails there).

Answer (score 0):

It might be if you have a metro web broswer set as the default.  It works perfectly if I have a desktop browser.

Also are you making sure you aren't doing something else on another thread or something that is clogging up the CPU usage?

Comment: I tried setting the Desktop-IE as the default, which didn't speed the process up. When clicking the link, the application is completely idle, and the button-press literally does nothing more then constructing the URL-object and calling LaunchUriAsync.

Comment: Did you try putting www. in the URI? I have no real idea, it shouldn't happen.

This is my C# code.
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.bytecode.ca/"));

Comment: I tried that, didn't help. But I made an interesting discovery: When I'm offline, the delay isn't there.